# Logic Error with Looping in Smarty?

Tags: php, smarty

Given the array:

```
$fruits = array(
    array(
        'color' => 'red',
        'name' => 'apple'
    ),
    array(
        'color' => 'red',
        'name' => 'cherry'
    ),
    array(
        'color' => 'yellow',
        'name' => 'banana'
    )
);
```

I'm trying to display this in Smarty so that it looks something like this:

```
red
 1. apple
 2. cherry

yellow
 1. banana
```

My code:

```
{foreach from=$fruits item=fruit}
    {assign var="current_color" value=$fruit.color}
    <h1>{$current_color}</h1>
        <ol>
            {while $current_color === $fruit.color}
                <li>{$fruit.name}</li>
                {assign var="fruit" value=$fruits|next}
            {/while}
        </ol>
{/foreach}
```

My incorrect results:

```
red
 1. apple
 2. cherry

red
 1. cherry

yellow
 1. banana
```

Any ideas what's wrong with my code? When I advance the array pointer in the while-loop, does it not affect the array in the foreach-loop?

**UPDATE 1:**

Tried using a for-loop:

```
{for $iteration=0 to $fruits|count - 1}
    {assign var="current_color" value=$fruits.{$iteration}.color}
    <h1>{$current_color}</h1>
        <ol>
            {while $current_color === $fruits.{$iteration}.color}
                <li>{$fruits.{$iteration}.name}</li>
                {assign var="iteration" value=$iteration + 1}
            {/while}
            {assign var="iteration" value=$iteration - 1}
        </ol>
{/for}
```

On the second iteration of the for-loop, I get the following error:

> Severity: Notice Message: Undefined property: Smarty_Variable::$step
>
> Severity: Notice Message: Undefined property: Smarty_Variable::$total

Comment: The PHP foreach structure makes a copy of the array for iteration, I think, so assuming Smarty is using it, I don't think you could affect its internal pointer.

Comment: *"When I advance the array pointer in the while-loop, does it not affect the array in the foreach-loop?"* Obviously it does, otherwise you should see apple again not only cherry. Also you're not advancing after quit the inner loop. At least this is how I read the output.

Comment: You are making things too complicated. You can do this easily with a single loop construct; just remember the last color and if it's different than the current one close the `</ol>` and output a new `<h1>` and `</ol>`.

Comment: @Jon - that is what I am trying to do. Can you show how to do this with a single loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just handled it in PHP before passing it to Smarty.